# como detectar si un conjunto de numeros tienen 4 digitos o menos de 4 digitos en php if else

Tags: php, condiciones, else

tengo este problema yo tengo en una variable esto

```
$num = "1285";
```

y quiero que si el numero guardado es de 4 digitos me muestre un mensaje y si tiene menos de 4 digitos me muestre otro tipo de mensaje

osea si tiene 4 digitos me muestre por ejemplo "el numero tiene 4 digitos", y si el numero no tiene 4 digitos me muestre "no cumple con los 4 digitos"

no se si se puede hacer con if y else

porfa si me pueden ayudar

Comment: sólo números enteros? número de dígitos enteros? número de dígitos decimales? decimales y enteros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy sencillo, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera, utilizando [strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php):

```
    //CADENA A EVALUAR
    $str = '1234';
    //CON STRLEN OBTENEMOS LA LONGITUD DE DICHA CADENA Y VERIFICAMOS QUE SEA DE 4 DIGITOS
    if(strlen($str) == 4){
        echo 'el numero tiene 4 digitos';
    //SI NO CUMPLE LA CONDICION
    }else{
        echo 'no cumple con los 4 digitos';
    }
```

Comment: El que dio el punto negativo puede explicar el porque?, o si tiene un mejor ejemplo aportarlo...

Comment: Imagino que será porque no verifica el caracter de cada posición: solo verifica la longitud de una cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías también verificar si la cadena es solo numérica con la función [**`ctype_digit()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ctype-digit.php), si esto no se cumple (si es numérico), verificamos que se encuentre entre el rango mayor igual a `0` y menor igual a `9999` y que su longitud sea de 4 caracteres. Ejemplo:

```
$num = "1234";

if (!ctype_digit($num)) {
    echo "No es numérico.";
} else if(intval($num) >= 0 && intval($num) <= 9999 && strlen($num) == 4) {
    echo "El número tiene 4 dígitos.";
} else {
    echo "No cumple con los 4 dígitos.";
}
```

Para los siguientes casos, imprime:

```
// $num = "1234"; => El número tiene 4 dígitos.
// $num = "12345"; => No cumple con los 4 dígitos.
// $num = "123"; => No cumple con los 4 dígitos.
// $num = "12a45"; => No es numérico.
```

Comment: Y en el caso de `$num = "123";`, que sucede?

Comment: @julio Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Con `intval($num) >= 1000` te podes ahorra el `&& strlen($num) == 4`

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo así:

```
$es_valido = false;
$str = "1235"; // el dato que llega

$str .= ""; // lo convierto en string

if (strlen($str) === 4) { 
    // verifico que cada posición de la cadena sea un int
    for ($contador = 0; $contador < 4; $contador++) {
        if  (filter_var( $str[$contador], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
            $es_valido = true;
        } else {
            $es_valido = false;
            break; // corto al primer error
        }
    }

}
if ($es_valido) {
    echo "El número es válido";
} else {
    echo "El número no es válido";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

dividiendo por 1000, usando [logaritmo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritmo) en base 10, (reemplazando puntos y comas y ...) calculando la longitud de la cadena.

```
<?php
$num=3114.315;
if (1 < $num / 1000 ) :
  echo 'al menos 4 dígitos enteros' . PHP_EOL; 
else :
 echo 'menos de 4 dígitos enteros' . PHP_EOL; 
endif;

$dig = 1+intval(floor(log10($num)));

if ( 4 === $dig ) :
 echo 'exactamente 4 dígitos enteros' . PHP_EOL; 
else :
 echo 'no tiene 4 dígitos enteros' . PHP_EOL; 
endif;

echo "{$num} tiene {$dig} dígitos enteros" . PHP_EOL;

$rep = str_replace([',','.'], '', $num);
$len = strlen($rep);

echo "{$num} tiene {$len} números ({$rep})" . PHP_EOL;
```

`intval(floor(` es por ciertas cuestiones de redondeo en diversas versiones de php. lo que nos interesa es la [parte entera de la carasteristica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritmo_decimal#Caracter%C3%ADstica_y_mantisa) para obtener el número de cifras.

Comment: dependerá de q tanto se quiera complicar la cosa, si es relevante saber si `is_numeric` o `is_int` o `$num===$num*1` dividir por 1000 es la mas simple el logaritmo es por si se quiere ajustar la cantidad de digitos, el contexto y que pasa antes o después con el número va a ir definiendo q tipo de expresión usar